# SortedList implementation in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I've implemented a SortedList which takes in streams of floats and returns a median at any point.

```
public class SortedList {

        float[] list;
        int pos;
        int capacity;

        public SortedList(){
            this.pos = 0;
            this.capacity = 2;
            list = new float[capacity];
        }

        public void offer(int item){
            if(pos == 0){
                list[pos] = item;
                pos++;
                return;
            }
            if(pos == 1){
                if(item > list[0]){
                    list[1] = item;
                }else{
                    float temp = list[0];
                    list[0] = item;
                    list[1] = temp;

                }
                pos++;
                return;
            }
            if(pos - list.length <= 1) resize();
            int index = -1;
            for(int i=0; i< pos -1; i++){
                if(item < list[i]){
                    index = i;
                    break;

                }else if((item > list[i] && item < list[i+1])){
                    index = i+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(index > -1){
                for(int i= pos; i > index; i--){
                    list[i] = list[i -1];
                }
                list[index] = item;

            }else{
                list[pos] = item;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        public float median(){
            float median = -1;
            if(pos%2 == 0){
                median = (list[pos/2 -1] + list[(pos/2)])/2;
            }else{
                median = list[(pos/2)];
            }
            return median;
        }
        private void resize(){

            capacity = capacity*2;
            float[] arr = new float[capacity];
            for(int i=0; i< pos; i++){
                arr[i] = list[i];
            }
            list = arr;
        }

        public void trace(){
            for(int i=0; i< pos; i++){
                System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Invite comments on efficiency and accuracy. In the test case that I've used it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Please protect your internals by preceding them with **`private`**:

```
private float[] list;
private int pos;
private int capacity;
```

**`pos`** is a very poor name for a field caching the size of the list: **`size`** is more clear.

You don't need **`capacity`**, just ask **`list.length`**.

Instead of **`trace()`**, I would override the **`String toString()`** method.

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SortedList {

    private float[] list;
    private int size;

    public SortedList() {
        this.list = new float[2];
    }

    public void offer(float item) {
        if (size == list.length) {
            expandArray();
        }

        int i = 0;

        for (; i < size; ++i) {
            if (list[i] > item) {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = size - 1; j >= i; --j) {
            list[j + 1] = list[j];
        }

        list[i] = item;
        size++;
    }

    public float median() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return Float.NaN;
        }

        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            return (list[size / 2 - 1] + list[(size / 2)]) / 2;
        } else {
            return list[(size / 2)];
        }
    }

    private void expandArray() {
        float[] arr = new float[2 * list.length];
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, arr, 0, list.length);
        list = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("[");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            sb.append(list[i]);

            if (i < size - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }

        return sb.append(']').toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        SortedList l = new SortedList();
        Random random = new Random(seed);

        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            l.offer(random.nextInt(100));
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 functions that will help you with this class: [java.util.Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-float:A-int-int-float-) and [java.lang.System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).

The will search and copy the data much more effectively than what you are doing now:

```
public void offer(int item){

    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(list, item, 0, pos);
    if(index<0) index = -index+1

    if(pos - list.length <= 1) resize();

    System.arraycopy(list, index, list, index+1, pos - index);
    list[index] = item;

}
```

Also for resize you can use [java.util.Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-float:A-int-) which can be faster than your own loop.